# Outer measure and measurable sets: why not change the outer measure definition?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If I understand correctly, the outer measure $m^*$ suffers from the undesirable defect that there are disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ such that $m^*(A\cup B) < m^*(A) + m^*(B)$. To deal with this, a set $E$ is said to be measurable if for all sets $A$ we have $m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A \cap E^c) = m^*(A)$.

I'm wondering why we go this roundabout way of correcting the defect. Couldn't have have just defined the outer measure to be countably additive, if that's what we really want?

Comment: But an outer measure is defined on *all subsets*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we added to all the requirements we want the countable additivity we would stumble upon a problem: such conditions are mutually inconsistent, meaning that there can't exists such a measure. So we need to weaken our requirements to what it's known as an outer measure in order to make a non-void definition.

You can take a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure) and I strongly recommend the introduction of Chapter 1 of Folland for an extensive explanation.

Comment: Thanks. What is the title of the Folland book?

Comment: ["Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications"](http://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Modern-Techniques-Applications/dp/0471317160). There should be a "look inside" option.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason is the original outer measure.  Lebesgue outer measure.  As defined by Lebesgue.  Because there are sets that are not Lebesgue measurable, we know that Lebesgue outer measure is only subadditive, not additive.  When Caratheodory made the definition of "outer measure", one of the things that he was generalizing was Lebesgue outer measure.